# iframe shows vertical scrollbars in IE8/9 only

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a iframe enclosed in a div of the main page. So the code is as follows;

```
<DIV id=abcPanel>
<IFRAME style="WIDTH: 660px; HEIGHT: 680px" id=abciFrame src="/someSrc" name=abciFrame></IFRAME>
</DIV>
```

Now the vertical scrollbar is shown in IE 8/9 , but not in other browsers.

Even if I increase the height to any value, the scrollbar does not go away. How do I fix the issue ?

Comment: Is the content of the iframe taller than 680px? You could try setting "overflow: hidden" on the iframe.

Comment: No..it is not actually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS: `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: Where do I apply that ? To the div or iframe ?

Answer (score 2):

If overflow:hidden on the iframe doesn;t work try adding these properties to it:

```
scrolling="no" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="no"
```

e.g.

```
<iframe scrolling="no" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: I had to use this method. $('<iframe>').css({overflow:'hidden'}) wasn't working for IE 8

Comment: scrolling="no" was enough for me

Answer (score 1):

add to the style of the iframe

```
overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code,

```
<DIV id=abcPanel>
<IFRAME style="WIDTH: 660px; overflow: hidden; HEIGHT: 680px" id=abciFrame src="/someSrc" name=abciFrame></IFRAME>
</DIV>
```